# Download file from json data created from MYSQL

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I want to show the data from MySQL in recyclerview.The data included with PDF files. Also want users to download that PDF files from with data manipulation

Answer (score 0):

So basically, these are the things you need -

1. [RecyclerView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview)  Basics
2. [Networking in Android](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes)
3. [Downloading files](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) in Android.

Sources -

- [CodePath](https://guides.codepath.com/android)
- [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)
- [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/index.html)